# Mails from Apple are shown malformed in Outlook 2010 (Windows)

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, signature

I have a setup with Mac and Windows clients. The Mac users use Apple Mail and all users have an HTML signature with images. When a Mac user replies to an email the text from the initial message becomes an attachment with the name: `untitled attachment001.html` and the image from the signature becomes an attachment with the name: `PastedGraphic.pdf`.

Can this behaviour be avoided? How can I preserve the original email and signature?

I have managed the following. I discovered that it was due to the malformed signature. So I created a .webarchive file that contains the signature as I want to be. The signature appears correctly at both the file and the apple mail signature editor. But when I open to write a new mail only the borders of the signature image appear and there is an '?' inside the borders. What does this mean?

Comment: Have you considered plain text sigs?

Comment: Anbd what about images?

Comment: @peraueb8921 Re: your edits, is the question mark in a blue box? Do you see the question mark on the Mac before sending or in Windows after receipt?

Comment: Almost...I made a step forward. I managed to see correlty the signature while I write a new mail. The message appears perfectly on Thunderbird but outlook says it cannot load 'cause a broken link:O

Answer (score 1):

The Mac users need to make sure that their outgoing email format is HTML or Rich Text even if the incoming format was plain text or use a plain text signature.

I'd prefer the latter: I use plain text email whenever possible as it's more-widely compatible and usually is easier to read. This, by necessity, would entail using plain text signatures.

Comment: The outgoing mails are in rich text(does apple mail support outgoing in html?). I have tried to disable inline attachments but nothing happened. Seriously, Apple mail is so lame?

Comment: @peraueb8921 Is "use the same message format as the original message" checked?

Comment: @peraueb8921 I believe that Mail's Rich Text is equivalent to HTML on Outlook.

Comment: @peraueb8921 Have you tried Outlook for Mac? If you're having trouble with Mail, it might be worth it to switch to a different email client.

Comment: Check my edits please

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have outlook licence

Comment: @peraueb8921 Microsoft has 30-day trials of Office (http://www.microsoft.com/mac/trial) that include Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

A similar discussion is covered here and speaks of some settings i your Apple Mail Application itself:
[Why my mails sent using Apple Mail have blank body in Outlook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278202/why-my-mails-sent-using-apple-mail-have-blank-body-in-outlook)
hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. If the content of this link does answer the question: please include the most relevant details in a quote from there. Links rot. Link-only answers are not that useful.