# Why my mails sent using Apple Mail have blank body in Outlook?

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office

When I send emails using Apple Mail to my colleagues (they use Outlook on Windows, various versions), it often happens that the mail looks blank and its body is split into various attachments.

[image: Body is blank. Its content splitted in a number of html attachments]

Even the signature and the signature's images are moved into attachments. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution. In the options screen, select **Composing**. Then, under **When quoting text in replies** or forwards select **Include all of the original**.

[image: Highlited option should be selected]